# Dual boot: Linux Boot option disappear

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot, grub, uefi

So I installed [Pop!_OS](https://system76.com/pop) while having Windows installed everything was working great.

The way I was choosing between the operating systems was by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and that opens a boot menu for my laptop so there is no Grub involved I think.

The issue is that after I changed the boot order from the bios (I moved Windows 10 first) the Linux option disappear from the boot menu. Even if I tried to move the Linux back first it still won't show up :/.

So is there a way to fix this issue, other than reinstalling the Linux distribution?

Edit 1: 
The way I updated the boot order:

1. Opened the bios
2. Went to this tab
3. Swapped Windows Boot Loader with the Linux one (it doesn't show up anymore)
4. Save and Restart
5. Test that by default it boots in windows
6. Noticed the issue (there is no Linux option anymore)

PS. Sorry for the image, I have no idea if it is possible to take a screenshot in bios :)

[image]

Comment: `I changed the boot order from the bios (I moved Windows 10 first)`, please explain in detail what exactly you did. Mention all the steps in the question.

Comment: ok give me one second

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a livedisk and then live boot. In the live environment, run these commands:

**For SATA drives**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo cp -n /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/

sudo chroot /mnt
apt install --reinstall linux-generic linux-headers-generic
update-initramfs -c -k all
exit
sudo bootctl --path=/mnt/boot/efi install
```

**For NVME drives**

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo cp -n /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/

sudo chroot /mnt
apt install --reinstall linux-generic linux-headers-generic
update-initramfs -c -k all
exit
sudo bootctl --path=/mnt/boot/efi install
```

In this code, `sda1` is the `/boot` partition and `sda3` is the `/root` partition which might be different for your installation. Run `lsblk` to make sure you are choosing the right hard drive and partitions.

All the details can be found in this link. https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/

follow the systemd-boot section of this link as I think you do not have GRUB.